# Difference between Piping and Reading Input

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

What is the difference between `cmd1 > tmp && cmd2 < tmp` and `cmd1 | cmd2`, besides the creation of a tmp file (obviously) ?

If my comprehension of pipe is right, I expect `cmd2` to read from **standard input** the output of `cmd1` in both cases, so I was expecting the same behaviour from those two.

However with [this go program](https://github.com/antonmedv/gofx) that reads standard input, it works as intended with pipe, but with the second form, it acts as if no input were received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Go program appears to *explicitly* test whether standard input is a pipe, and if it is not, it exits with a diagnostic message:

```go
fi, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
if err != nil {
        fatal(err)
}
if fi.Mode()&os.ModeNamedPipe == 0 {
        usage()
        os.Exit(1)
}
```

The other difference between the two command lines is that with the pipe, the two commands are run simultaneously.  The left hand side command is writing and the right hand side command is reading.  If one is too slow for the other (in terms of reading/writing), the faster program will temporarily block until the slower catches up.

In the case where the two commands are run with `&&` in-between them, they are obviously run after each other.  The second command will not start until the first command has finished and has terminated with a zero exit status.